# In angular on click filter data from list of objects

Tags: angularjs, angular

```
0: {user_id: 1, status: Active, account_request_status: 2, first_name: null, last_name: null, email: null,…}
1: {user_id: 3, status: Inactive, account_request_status: 0, first_name: null, last_name: null, email: null,…}
2: {user_id: 37, status: Rejected, account_request_status: 0, first_name: null, last_name: null, email: null,…}
3: {user_id: 39, status: Pending, account_request_status: 0, first_name: null, last_name: null, email: null,…}
4: {user_id: 37, status: Rejected, account_request_status: 0, first_name: null, last_name: null, email: null,…}
5: {user_id: 39, status: Pending, account_request_status: 0, first_name: null, last_name: null, email: null,…}
1: {user_id: 3, status: Inactive, account_request_status: 0, first_name: null, last_name: null, email: null,…}

HTML - 
<div class="mb-5 md:mb-0">
                        <a class="rounded-md py-2 px-8 mr-2 bg-blue-500 font-bold text-white">Active</a>
</div>
<div class="mb-5 md:mb-0">
                        <a class="rounded-md py-2 px-8 mr-2 bg-blue-500 font-bold text-white">Inactive/a>
                    </div>
<div class="mb-5 md:mb-0">
                        <a class="rounded-md py-2 px-8 mr-2 bg-blue-500 font-bold text-white">Rejected</a>
                    </div>
<div class="mb-5 md:mb-0">
                        <a class="rounded-md py-2 px-8 mr-2 bg-blue-500 font-bold text-white">Pending</a>
                    </div>
```

I want to **filter** the list of objects on the basis of **Status** when clicked on respective buttons.
Suppose I click on **active button** only objects with **status active** must be shown in the **list**.
How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

component.html

```
<div class="mb-5 md:mb-0">
<a class="rounded-md py-2 px-8 mr-2 bg-blue-500 font-boldtext-white" (click)="filterBystatus('Active')">Active</a>
</div>
<div class="mb-5 md:mb-0">
<a class="rounded-md py-2 px-8 mr-2 bg-blue-500 font-boldtext-white" (click)="filterBystatus('Inactive')">Inactive</a>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
  data;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = [
      {
        user_id: 1,
        status: "Active",
        account_request_status: 2,
        first_name: null,
        last_name: null,
        email: null
      },
      {
        user_id: 1,
        status: "Inactive",
        account_request_status: 2,
        first_name: null,
        last_name: null,
        email: null
      }
    ];
    console.log(this.filterBystatus("Active"));
    console.log(this.filterBystatus("Inactive"));
  }

  filterBystatus(status) {
    return this.data.filter(item => item.status === status);
  }
```